# SQL Server Ranking

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ranking

I have a table of stocks that I would like to create rolling ranks for each stock.

Here's a sample of my dataset:

```
StockID QuoteID QuoteDay    QuoteClose
47      230     2018-04-06  5.1200
47      231     2018-04-07  5.2100
47      232     2018-04-08  5.3000
47      233     2018-04-09  5.2100
47      234     2018-04-10  5.1900
47      235     2018-04-11  5.5200
47      236     2018-04-12  7.1600
47      237     2018-04-13  6.6900
47      238     2018-04-14  6.6300
47      239     2018-04-15  7.0200
47      240     2018-04-16  6.6300
47      241     2018-04-17  6.5800
251     100     2018-04-06  0.1906
251     101     2018-04-07  0.1969
251     102     2018-04-08  0.1986
251     103     2018-04-09  0.2291
251     104     2018-04-10  0.1963
251     105     2018-04-11  0.1995
251     106     2018-04-12  0.2271
251     107     2018-04-13  0.3722
251     108     2018-04-14  0.3073
251     109     2018-04-15  0.3292
251     110     2018-04-16  0.2905
251     111     2018-04-17  0.2784
```

Each day, I want to rank the QuoteClose over the preceding 6 days.

For example:

```
StockID QuoteID QuoteDay    QuoteClose  7d Rank
47      230     04/06/18     5.1200     
47      231     04/07/18     5.2100     
47      232     04/08/18     5.3000     
47      233     04/09/18     5.2100     
47      234     04/10/18     5.1900     
47      235     04/11/18     5.5200     
47      236     04/12/18     7.1600       1
47      237     04/13/18     6.6900       2
47      238     04/14/18     6.6300       3
47      239     04/15/18     7.0200       2
47      240     04/16/18     6.6300       4
47      241     04/17/18     6.5800       6
251     100     04/06/18     0.1906     
251     101     04/07/18     0.1969     
251     102     04/08/18     0.1986     
251     103     04/09/18     0.2291     
251     104     04/10/18     0.1963     
251     105     04/11/18     0.1995     
251     106     04/12/18     0.2271       2
251     107     04/13/18     0.3722       1
251     108     04/14/18     0.3073       2
251     109     04/15/18     0.3292       2
251     110     04/16/18     0.2905       4
251     111     04/17/18     0.2784       5
```

Note that the first 6 days do not have a ranking.

I am having problems combining rank with row number, so my approach is have a loop that feeds in only 7 days of data at a time for each stock.

For example, for stock #47, on 4/12/18, I'm comparing Quoteclose from 4/6/8-4/12/8 to determine that the ranking will be 1.

I then save that ranking to another table.

The loop will then shift the window forward 1 day and find the ranking for 4/13/18 which will be 2.  The process is repeated for this stock and then for all other stocks in the table.

My plan is convoluted, but should get the job done.

**Are there better and cleaner ways to accomplish this rolling rank for all stocks?**

I'm trying to make this a dynamic process so I can generate different ranking periods: 7day, 20day, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Breaking this up into steps:

First (**OrderedRankSets** CTE) get a set of rows for each StockID and QuoteDay that include the current row and all prior rows, numbered descending by the QuoteDay. We can later use this numbering to limit the prior rows we're going to rank.

Second (**RankedQuoteDays** CTE), rank each of these quote sets where we actually have at least the number of rows in the period for each quote day and only include the rows up to the period length.

Finally, we don't need to output all the rows for the sets, we just need the most current for each quote day (quote day = prior quote day) so the final query just dumps that (see [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/64be7/26))

```
DECLARE @Period INT = 7;

WITH 
    OrderedRankSets AS (
       SELECT
            Quotes.StockID
        ,   Quotes.QuoteID
        ,   Quotes.QuoteDay
        ,   PriorQuotes.QuoteDay AS PriorQuoteDay
        ,   PriorQuotes.QuoteClose
        ,   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Quotes.StockID, Quotes.QuoteDay ORDER BY PriorQuotes.QuoteDay DESC) AS RowNumber
        ,   COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Quotes.StockID, Quotes.QuoteDay) AS [RowCount]
        FROM 
            Quotes
        JOIN Quotes AS PriorQuotes ON (PriorQuotes.StockID = Quotes.StockID
                                       AND PriorQuotes.QuoteDay <= Quotes.QuoteDay)
    )
,  RankedQuoteDays AS (
       SELECT 
          OrderedRankSets.*
       ,  CASE WHEN [RowCount] < @Period THEN NULL ELSE RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY StockID, QuoteDay ORDER BY QuoteClose DESC) END AS QuoteRank
       FROM
          OrderedRankSets
       WHERE
          RowNumber <= @Period
   )
SELECT
    RankedQuoteDays.StockID
,   RankedQuoteDays.QuoteID
,   RankedQuoteDays.QuoteDay
,   RankedQuoteDays.QuoteClose
,   RankedQuoteDays.QuoteRank
FROM
    RankedQuoteDays
WHERE
    QuoteDay = PriorQuoteDay
ORDER BY
    StockID, QuoteDay
```

Comment: I'm trying to INSERT the output INTO a new table, but am having problems with the last WHERE statement, any suggestions?

Comment: Do you get an error? It should work if you just put an INSERT INTO before the last SELECT statement (i.e. INSERT the results of the SELECT statement into the table). Or add an INTO clause to the SELECT and write it into a new table.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your ranking but I am assuming it is a 7 (variable day) rolling average ranked from best(largest number) to worst (smallest)

```
declare  @t table (
StockID int,    QuoteID int,    QuoteDay date,  QuoteClose money)
insert into @t
values
    (47,230,'20180406',5.12)
,   (47,231,'20180407',5.21)
,   (47,232,'20180408',5.3)
,   (47,233,'20180409',5.21)
,   (47,234,'20180410',5.19)
,   (47,235,'20180411',5.52)
,   (47,236,'20180412',7.16)
,   (47,237,'20180413',6.69)
,   (47,238,'20180414',6.63)
,   (47,239,'20180415',7.02)
,   (47,240,'20180416',6.63)
,   (47,241,'20180417',6.58)
,   (251,100,'20180406',0.1906)
,   (251,101,'20180407',0.1969)
,   (251,102,'20180408',0.1986)
,   (251,103,'20180409',0.2291)
,   (251,104,'20180410',0.1963)
,   (251,105,'20180411',0.1995)
,   (251,106,'20180412',0.2271)
,   (251,107,'20180413',0.3722)
,   (251,108,'20180414',0.3073)
,   (251,109,'20180415',0.3292)
,   (251,110,'20180416',0.2905)
,   (251,111,'20180417',0.2784)

declare @dayInRank int = 7


;with cte as
(
    select rn=row_number()over(partition by StockID order by QuoteDay)
        ,*
    from @t
)

,RollingAvg as
(
    select StockID,QuoteDay,RollingAvg=s.RollingSum/@dayInRank
    from cte
        cross apply (select SUM(QuoteClose) from cte c2 where cte.StockID=c2.StockID and c2.rn between cte.rn-(@dayInRank-1) and cte.rn) s(RollingSum) 
    where rn>=@dayInRank
)

select *,Rank=Row_Number()over (partition by StockID order by ra.RollingAvg desc)
from RollingAvg ra
order by StockID,QuoteDay
```

Comment: I suggest testing with a smaller @dayInRank value to really see how this query works